UserControl custom ItemsSource set not called
Reference: Custom ItemsSource property for a UserControl
I have a custom UserControl to display a set of aggregate data for the window it's contained in (a list of downloads). The basics of the containing window are
<Grid>
  <StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer>
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Downloads}">
        .
        .
        .
      </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <local:DownloadStatsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Downloads}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>

The behind code for the UserControl contains
    public DownloadStatsControl()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      DataContext = this;
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
      get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
      set
      {
        if (value == null)
          ClearValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        else
          SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
      }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemsSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(DownloadStatsControl),
                                          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourceChanged)));

    private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      var control = sender as DownloadStatsControl;

      control?.OnItemsSourceChanged((FixedSizeQueue<DownloadState>)e.OldValue, (FixedSizeQueue<DownloadState>)e.NewValue);
    }

The ItemsControl is displaying data from the bound source (Downloads). The UserControl is not displaying data. My challenge is the set for ItemsSource isn't called. The constructor is called.
Of note: The code above is different from the referenced SO. When I wasn't getting the set called, I referred to the ItemControl source and pulled it back to basics (i.e., just use IEnumerable).
What am I missing here?
Edit: Thanks to the linked answer, it got me closer. Yes, my UserControl was using itself as the DataContext. However, after making the change to reference the parent, it still didn't call the setter. It wasn't until I searched a bit more and ran across WPF Binding to parent DataContext where I had all the pieces I needed.
<local:DownloadStatsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Downloads, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>

Thanks for the pointers.

The problem is DataContext = this;. It breaks ItemsSource="{Binding Downloads}", as now Downloads is expected to be a property of DownloadStatsControl.

You should also not call anything else than SetValue in the setter of the CLR wrapper of a dependency property. The setter is not called when the property is set by a Binding or a Style Setter. The ClearValue call is redundant anyway, since it just restores the property's default value null, which is identical to what is passed as value in that case.

@Clemens The setter code mirrors that of the code found in the official ItemControl repository.

Sure, but it is unclear why they are doing it. Yours is a just a normal custom control that should adhere to the general rules. See Implications for custom dependency properties here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/xaml-loading-and-dependency-properties.
